# Javascript regex, determining what group was matched on

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following regex in javascript for matching similar to `book[n]`, `book[1,2,3,4,5,...,n]`, `book[author="Kristian"]` and `book[id=n]` (n is an arbitrary number):

```
var opRegex = /\[[0-9]+\]|\[[0-9]+,.*\]|\[[a-zA-Z]+="*.+"*\]/gi;
```

I can use this in the following way:

```
// If there is no match in any of the groups hasOp will be null
hasOp = opRegex.exec('books[0]');

/*
Result: ["[0]", index: 5, input: "books[0]"]
*/
```

As shown above I not only get the value but also the [ and ]. I can avoid this by using groups. So I changed the regex to:

```
var opRegex = /\[([0-9]+)\]|\[([0-9]+,.*)\]|\[([a-zA-Z]+=".+")\]/gi;
```

Running the same as above the results will instead be:

```
["[0]", "0", undefined, undefined, index: 5, input: "books[0]"]
```

Above I get the groups as index 1, 2 and 3 in the array. For this example the match is in the first but if the match is in the second regex group the match will be in index 2 or the array.

Can I change my first regex to get the value without the brackets or do I go with the grouped approach and a while loop to get the first defined value?

Anything else I'm missing? Is it greedy?

Let me know if you need more information and I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few suggestions. First, especially since you are looking for literal brackets, avoid the regex brackets when you can (replace `[0-9]` with `\d`, for example). Also, you were allowing multiple quotes with the `*`, so I changed it to `"?`. But most importantly, I moved the match for the brackets outside the alternation, since they should be in every alternate match. That way, you have the same group no matter which part matches.

```
/\[(\d+(,\d+)*|[a-zA-Z]+="?[^\]]+"?)\]/gi
```

Comment: Works great! Can you just explain the "outside the alternation ... every alternate match". I didn't quite get that.

Comment: Basically, you needed the brackets outside the grouping (parens) so they weren't part of the matched group. You did that in your second regex, but you had three separate groupings instead of one main one. In the solution, there is only one set of parens, so only one group.